# Best way to remove special characters xslt 1.0

Tags: templates, xslt-1.0

We received xml files from England but now also from France. In those France files there are a lot of special characters in different nodes. Special the ' gives problems when we in the end of the process the data want to upload with an insert query in a database.
It is possible to replace the nodes with translate function, but there are a lot of nodes. 
I understand it should also possible to do this with the (apply)template function, but I don’t know how.
We need to replace for example the ' with &rsquo. Can someone give an example?

Comment: If `translate()` works for you, why don't you apply it to all nodes? It shouldn't matter how many nodes there are, the stylesheet can process them all recursively. Note that `translate()` works on individual characters only, not on codes like `&rsquo;`.

Comment: We have this issue on multiple places in multiple processes. It will be a lot of work and also the readability will not be better.

Comment: I am not sure what you describe - you show us no code. In general, you only need one template matching `text()` to process all text nodes in the entire document.

Comment: Sorry I write down the name of an other example I found (&rsquo).
An example what I receive:
<name>O'Brien<name> I need this to replace, including the nodes, with <name>O’Brien<name>.
This other quote is not an issue in SQL.